# Using Symbols in FitSharp

Tags: .net, fitnesse, fitsharp

I'm trying to use [Symbols](http://fitnesse.org/FitNesse.UserGuide.FixtureGallery.ImportantConcepts.FixtureSymbols) in my .NET FitNesse fixtures, using the last version of FitSharp (release.1.8.net.40.zip), like this:

```
!|Player Registers           |
|username|password|player id?|
|john    |test123 |>>player  |
```

The symbol, "player",  is ignored:

> [1] expected [>>player]

I tried to load the handlers:

```
!|Cell Handler Loader               |
|load|SymbolSaveHandler  |FitLibrary|
|load|SymbolRecallHandler|FitLibrary|
```

But it doesn't seem to work:

> Could not find class CellHandlerLoader

There were some library changes, as described here: http://fitsharp.github.com/Fit/BreakingChanges.html

Any help would be appreciated.

Thank you!

**Update**:

My fixture code:

```
namespace Example.Tests.FitNesse {
    public class PlayerRegisters : ColumnFixture {
        public string Username;
        public string Password;
        public int PlayerId() {
            return 1;
        }
    }
}
```

Suite config file (example.config.xml):

```
<suiteConfig>
    <ApplicationUnderTest>
        <AddAssembly>c:\Users\Marcel\Documents\dev\dotnet\Example.Tests.FitNesse\bin\x86\Debug\Example.Tests.FitNesse.dll</AddAssembly>
        <AddNamespace>Example.Tests.FitNesse</AddNamespace>
    </ApplicationUnderTest>
</suiteConfig>
```

And FitNesse root page:

```
!define TEST_SYSTEM {slim}
!define COMMAND_PATTERN {%m -c c:\fitnesse\dotnet\example.config.xml -r fitSharp.Slim.Service.Runner,c:\fitnesse\dotnet\fitsharp.dll}
!define TEST_RUNNER {c:\fitnesse\dotnet\Runner.exe}
```

I've tried including **fit.dll** to my assemblies: https://github.com/jediwhale/fitsharp/issues#issue/62

Also tried adding some operators...

Comment: Can you post your fixture code, suite config file if any and your FitNesse command_pattern and test_runner definitions?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

OK, I've got it!

This fixtures work fine in **Fit** but not in **Slim**.

Just changed my root page:

```
!path c:\Users\Marcel\Documents\dev\dotnet\Example.Tests.FitNesse\bin\x86\Debug\Example.Tests.FitNesse.dll
!define COMMAND_PATTERN {%m -r fitnesse.fitserver.FitServer,c:\fitnesse\dotnet\fit.dll %p}
!define TEST_RUNNER {c:\fitnesse\dotnet\Runner.exe}
```

Answer (score 3):

I had this same problem. The answer is that fitSharp has a different symbol syntax.

Try this

```
!|Player Registers            |
 |username|password|player id?|
 |john    |test123 |$player=  |
```

Then access the symbol using just $player.